# Modal dialogue inside list item not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to be a little devious, and put a modal dialog inside a list item in a navbar, the idea is to replace the entire list item with Ajax later on. This is to help with some donut caching I'm going to add shortly.

Starting with a completely standard MVC-5 template (normal), all I have added is the following:

**Shared Controller**:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication8.Models;

namespace WebApplication8.Controllers
{
    public class SharedController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Basket()
        {
            return PartialView("_Basket", new Basket());
        }
    }
}
```

**Basket Model**:

```
namespace WebApplication8.Models
{
    public class Basket
    {
        public int Count {
            get { return 3; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Basket partial view**

```
@model WebApplication8.Models.Basket

<li id="Cart">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cart-modal">Cart (@Model.Count)</a>

    <div class="modal fade" id="cart-modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
</li>
```

**Changed Navbar section of Shared Layout View**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
    @Html.Action("Basket", "Shared")
</ul>
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
```

And there you have it, everything you need to add to the standard MVC5 template to recreate this effect.

A screenshot is below, but the modal pops up, it is just still in the background. None of the buttons are clickable, no errors in Chrome's console:

[image: Not right]

Is there anything I can do here to fix this, or is this just not going to work?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with asp.net it's a client side (javascript) issue. Read again bootstrap examples

Comment: @MikeSW Thanks, do you have an idea as to what might be wrong?

Comment: No, try http://codereview.stackexchange.com it's a better place for your problem

Comment: Isn't codereview for working code you could improve? My code doesn't work.